# Проблема с отправко и получением почты на домен

Tags: dns, домен

Не так давно пявилась проблема с почтой, раньше сервер нормально отправлял сообщения (уведомления) пользователям на почту потом начали приходить на почту домена сообщения об ошибках отправки, теперь домен (сервер) вовсе не хочет получать и отправлять сообщения по email.
Проблема в DNS записях домена, помогите настроить коректно DNS записи домена для получения и отправки почты.
Заранее спасибо!)
(домен зарегестрирован на Hostinger, сайт стоит на VDS под управлением ISP)

Скрин с настройки DNS зоны:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: С чего вы решили, что проблема в DNS?

Comment: Кажется так, возможно что проблема в самом ISP?

Comment: начинайте с логов почтового сервера, там может быть написано много интересного. потом подключитесь телнетом к 25 порту своего сервера и в ручном режиме (сначала по ip, потом по имени указанном в MX) попробуйте отправить письмо. (построчно: `HELO test.com`, `MAIL FROM: адрес@отправителя`, `RCPT TO: адрес@получателя`, `DATA`, тело письма, `.`)

Comment: Спасибо, буду пробовать.